# How to prevent Safari url address bar from overlapping bottom of mobile browser on iOS 13 when keyboard is open?

Tags: css, ios, iphone, mobile, responsive-design

I understand this is a highly specific question, but I will try and ask it as best I can.

We have a chat application that takes up the entire viewport when open on web browsers on mobile devices.

In most cases it works as expected.

But we had a friend who tested it on his iPhone 13 with Safari and we noticed that the URL Address bar was overlapping the text input field when the keyboard was open.

[image]

I am unsure what might be causing this, and we do not know if there is a way to mitigate this through code or if it just an odd setting in Safari particularly on iOS 13.

Is there any information on how to solve for this issue of the url bar overlapping?